# py2exe has inconsistent behavior with its source .py files

Tags: python, py2exe

My python program has many function which all seem to work fine when run from the .py script.  After compiling with py2exe several of the sections of code have very inconsistent behavior.

This section seems to be very consistent in its failure.

```
def unzipItem(self, fileName, destination):
    print "--unzipItem--"
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName)
    nameList = zip.namelist()

    fileCount = 0
    for item in nameList:
        fileCount += 1

    dlg = wx.ProgressDialog("Unziping files",
                           "An informative message",
                           fileCount,
                           parent = self,
                           )

    keepGoing = True
    count = 0

    for item in nameList:
        count += 1
        dir,file = os.path.split(item)
        print "unzip " + file

        self.SetStatusText("Unziping " + str(item))
        (keepGoing, skip) = dlg.Update(count, file)
        zip.extract(item,destination)

    zip.close()
    dlg.Destroy()
```

The ProcessDialog never appears, and the SetStatusText never updates the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real answer as to why this occured - but using cx_Freeze instead of py2exe solved this problem.